# AWS Glue: how to cast array using resolveChoice()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, casting, aws-glue

I have a schema in AWS Glue job.

```
|-- individual_lender_probs: array
|    |-- element: struct
|    |    |-- lender: string
|    |    |-- buy_rate: double
|    |    |-- approve_prob: double
```

How can I create a schema for this using resolveChoice()? It should be like df=df.resolveChoice(specs = [('individual_lender_probs','cast:**XXXX**')])

Answer (score 0):

ResolveChoice is used when you have a field that is not always with the same value type.
It is not clear in your example that it's accurate.

In a case that there is a choice to make, please visit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html to know how to behave